# How to declare variable and assign values in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, variables

I have tried to declare a variable and assign value to it. But I am always getting error message with error code: SQL state: 42601

Example of a simple SQL statement written within PostgreSQL is as per below:

DECLARE
dest_var TEXT;

dest_var = show log_destination;

Can anyone suggest on ways to overcome this problem?

Tried to google, search for tutorials on declaring variables in postgres

Comment: This has to happen inside a function or procedure. For `plpgsql` this is [Function structure](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-structure.html) with more details here [Declarations](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-declarations.html).

Comment: Thanks for highlighting that @adrianKlaver. Now I am getting an error within the function that says:
ERROR:  column "show" does not exist
LINE 1: dest_var := show log_destination.

How can I solve this any idea?

Comment: Put your content between quotes ': `dest_var := 'show log_destination';`

Comment: I did that, and it returned a value of null. But when I run the command: show log_destination alone, I can see some value being returned. Why is that the case? Could it be because of the command being in quotations?

Comment: Ok instead of putting the command as dest_var := 'show log_destination'; I have inserted an execute statement, and now it works.
code:
EXECUTE 'SHOW log_destination' INTO dest_var;
 Thanks for all the contributions! Appreciate the assistance

Comment: You can also [`select current_setting('log_destination') into dest_var;`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SET-TABLE). Demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/oMsFOrBK).